# Uncaught error: Illegal arguments running Dart compiled to js in Safari

Tags: safari, dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

Ok, not sure how easy this is going to be to get help with but here goes...

So there is Dart code I am dealing with which uses polymer, and perhaps another relevant detail is that there are a lot of `Futures` in it. When accessing the web page (you can see it here yourself: http://trommons.org/) loads fine in Chrome and Firefox, new versions at the least, but in Safari latest version the "Task stream" dart component (content directly under the "Translation tasks" header) doesn't work and hence displays the configured text "Loading..." while not actually doing anything.

This is work-related pretty much, for my internship as part of my undergrad degree, but thankfully due to the nature of the project this is open source so I am free to share code.

The TaskStream dart source and html (for polymer element and such) can be seen on our Github repo [here](https://github.com/TheRosettaFoundation/SOLAS-Match/tree/develop/ui/dart/web/Routes/Users).

So, the following is the Stack trace I get in Safari console when the project is built with dart2js in debug mode (did this on a "dev server" we have at work for site testing, it is not built in debug mode on the live site I linked):

```
Illegal argument(s) zone.dart:711 
(anonymous function) zone.dart:711 
callback$0 home.dart.js:13983
(anonymous function) schedule_microtask.dart:23 
(anonymous function) schedule_microtask.dart:32
(anonymous function) isolate helper.dart:1510
(anonymous function) js_helper.dart:1820
(anonymous function) isolate_helper.dart:355
(anonymous function) isolate_helper.dart:30
(anonymous function) js_helper.dart:1820
(anonymous function) js_helper.dart:1842
```

If anyone is willing to try to help with this, and has questions about the code/want help understanding parts of it, I will try to reply in a timely manner.

Comment: I'd file a bug on dartbug.com. If it works in Dartium/Chrome/Firefox. Is the Safari a current version?

Comment: Yeah, like I said latest version. OS X Mavericks, Safari 7.0.3